# Show when nonincreasing subsequence is bounded below, the sequence is bounded below

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_k)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function such that $(f(x_k))$ is nonincreasing. Suppose $x*$ be an accumulation point of $(x_k)$. Show that $(f(x_k))$ is bounded below for all $k$.

**My try:**

Since $x*$ is an accumulation point of $(x_k)$, there exist a subsequence $(x_{k_j})$ of $(x_k)$ converging to $x*$. Since $f$ is continuous, one has $f(x_{k_j}) \to f(x*)$. Since $(f(x_k))$ is nonincreasing any subsequence of it is nonincreasing. Thus, one can write $f(x*) \leq f(x_{k_j})$.
I want to show $f(x*)\le f(x_k) \quad \forall k$. I do not proceed further.

Comment: I think that your claim of "Since $f((x_k))$ is nonincreasing, any subsequence of it is nonincreasing" is false. Take $x_n=(1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,...)$. Clearly $x_n$ is a non increasing sequence but the subsequence of odd numbers is increasing.

Comment: @Carlos Jiménez: By nonincreasing I meant that every element is smaller to or equal to the next one.

Comment: @CarlosJiménez I believe "nonincreasing" does not mean "not increasing" in this context. It means that $x_{k + 1} \le x_k$ for all $k$, i.e. one term is never a (strict) increase from the previous one. The English language is a real pain sometimes. :-)

Comment: I can see now. Sorry for my misunderstanding. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.    Pick any integer $k$.  Then for some $j$, we have $k_j>k$, as the $k_j$ are a subsequence of the integers (e.g. an increasing sequence of integers tending to infinity).

Then $k_j>k$ implies that $f(x_{k_j})\leq f(x_k)$, by the non-increasing property of the $f(x_i)$.  Putting it all together we get: $$f(x*)\leq f(x_{k_j})\leq f(x_k),$$
as required.